# Is there a way to visualise specific UI elements in a Flutter application developed with Android Studio?

Tags: android, ios, android-studio, flutter

We can run entire apps in an emulator. Is there a way to visualise individual UI elements? It would be helpful, e.g. if I change the padding of a button, I want to see how the button would look like after the change without launching the entire application.

Answer (score 0):

> Install the Flutter and Dart plugins

To install these:

1. Start Android Studio.
   2.Open plugin preferences (Preferences > Plugins on macOS, File > Settings > Plugins on Windows & Linux).
2. Select Browse repositories, select the Flutter plugin and click Install.
3. Click Yes when prompted to install the Dart plugin.
4. Click Restart when prompted.

After that :
“Open existing Android Studio Project”

You can also visit this links : [Flutter Android Studio](https://flutter.io/get-started/editor/)